# Replace text in one data-frame using a look up to another data-frame

Tags: r, dataframe, match, gsub, mapply

I have the task of searching through text, replacing peoples names and nicknames with a generic character string.

Here is the structure of my data frame of names and corresponding nicknames:

```
names <- c("Thomas","Thomas","Abigail","Abigail","Abigail")
nicknames <- c("Tom","Tommy","Abi","Abby","Abbey")
df_name_nick <- data.frame(names,nicknames)
```

Here is the structure of my data frame containing text

```
text_names <- c("Abigail","Thomas","Abigail","Thomas","Colin")
text_comment <- c("Tommy sits next to Abbey","As a footballer Tommy is very good","Abby is a mature young lady","Tom is a handsome man","Tom is friends with Colin and Abi")
df_name_comment <- data.frame(text_names,text_comment)
```

Giving these dataframes

df_name_nick:

```
names nicknames
1  Thomas       Tom
2  Thomas     Tommy
3 Abigail       Abi
4 Abigail      Abby
5 Abigail     Abbey
```

df_name_comment:

```
text_names                       text_comment
1    Abigail           Tommy sits next to Abbey
2     Thomas As a footballer Tommy is very good
3    Abigail        Abby is a mature young lady
4     Thomas              Tom is a handsome man
5      Colin  Tom is friends with Colin and Abi
```

I am looking for a routine that will search through each row of df_name_comment and use the df_name_comment$text_names to look up the corresponding nickname from df_name_nick and replace it with XXX.
Note for each person's name there can be several nicknames.
Note that in each text comment, only the appropriate name for that row is replaced, so that we would get this as output:

```
Abigail "Tommy sits next to XXX"
Thomas  "As a footballer, XXX is very good"
Abigail "XXX is a mature young lady"
Thomas  "XXX is a handsome man"
Colin   "Tom is friends with Colin and Abi"
```

I’m thinking this will require a cunning combination of gsubs, matches and apply functions (either mapply, sapply, etc)

I've searched on Stack Overflow for something similar to this request and can only find very specific regex solutions based on data frames with unique row elements, and not something that I think will work with generic text lookups and gsubs via multiple nicknames.

Can anyone please help me solve my predicament?
With thanks

Nevil
(newbie R programmer since Jan 2017)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea via base R. We basically paste the nicknames together for each name, collapsed by `|` so as to pass it as regex in `gsub` and replace the matched words of each comment with XXX. We use `mapply` to do that after we merge our aggregated nicknames with `df_name_comment`.

```
d1 <- aggregate(nicknames ~ names, df_name_nick, paste, collapse = '|')
d2 <- merge(df_name_comment, d1, by.x = 'text_names', by.y = 'names', all = TRUE)
d2$nicknames[is.na(d2$nicknames)] <- 0
d2$text_comment <- mapply(function(x, y) gsub(x, 'XXX', y), d2$nicknames, d2$text_comment)
d2$nicknames <- NULL
d2
```

Which gives,

> ```
>   text_names                      text_comment
> 1    Abigail            Tommy sits next to XXX
> 2    Abigail        XXX is a mature young lady
> 3      Colin Tom is friends with Colin and Abi
> 4     Thomas  As a footballer XXX is very good
> 5     Thomas             XXX is a handsome man
> ```

**Note1**: Replacing NA in `nicknames` with 0 is due to the fact that NA (which is the default fill in `merge` for unmatched elements) would convert the comment string to NA as well when passed in `gsub`

**Note2** The order is also changed due to `merge`, but you can sort as you wish as per usual.

**Note3** Is better to have your variables as characters rather than factors. So you either read the data frames with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` or convert via,

```
df_name_comment[] <- lapply(df_name_comment, as.character)
df_name_nick[] <- lapply(df_name_nick, as.character)
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, we can simply match the comments' names with our aggregated data set, save that in a vector and use `mapply` directly on the original data frame, without having to merge and then drop variables, i.e.

```
#d1 as created above
v1 <- d1$nicknames[match(df_name_comment$text_names, d1$names)]
v1[is.na(v1)] <- 0

df_name_comment$text_comment <- mapply(function(x, y) gsub(x, 'XXX', y),
                                               v1, df_name_comment$text_comment)
```

Comment: Hi Sotos. I learned from your solution that I can also use "|" in a gsub statement. I don't mean to steal your idea, but I added that to my solution 2 (instead of first grepling and then gsubbing) to improve it, I hope you're okay with that.

Comment: @Florian, no problem at all :)

Comment: Hello Sotos. This looks great! I can easily have my nickname file in the format that you need from the outset, without the need to aggregate it from my originally stated structure. I did wonder whether I could include the or symbol (|) in the logic somewhere - you've shown me the way! Now I wonder if there is any way that avoids creating extra data frames or appending to existing data frames at any stage, and that can compare my two dataframes as separate entities throughout the routine ... or can R not do that?

Comment: You could but then you would have to use a nested `sapply` which will make the whole process even less efficient. You could however instead of merging, to match just the 2 columns and save that result in a separated vector and then use `mapy` with that. I ll add that in a few minutes

Comment: To conclude things, I've now successfully implemented Sotos' first solution and it's worked a treat. With thanks to everyone, including Florian's code that included using the great tip of the \\b regex to find whole words. All sorted now. Nevil

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps!

```
l <- apply(df_name_comment, 1, function(x) 
  ifelse(length(df_name_nick[df_name_nick$names==x["text_names"], "nicknames"]) > 0, 
         gsub(paste(df_name_nick[df_name_nick$names==x["text_names"], "nicknames"], collapse="|"),'XXX', x["text_comment"]),
         x["text_comment"]))
df_name_comment$text_comment <- as.list.data.frame(l)
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem :)*

Answer (score 0):

**Data**

```
df_name_nick <- data.frame(names,nicknames,stringsAsFactors = F)
df_name_comment <- data.frame(text_names,text_comment,stringsAsFactors = F)
```

---

**Solution 2**

> EDIT: In this initial solution I manually checked with grepl if the nickname was present, and then gsubbed with one of the matching ID's. I knew the '|' operator worked with grepl, but not with gsub. So credits to Sotos for that idea.

```
df = df_name_comment
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  matching_nicknames = df_name_nick$nicknames[df_name_nick$names==df$text_names[i]]
  if(length(matching_nicknames)>0)
  {
    df$text_comment[i] = mapply(sub, pattern=paste(paste0("\\b",matching_nicknames,"\\b"),collapse="|"), "XXX", df$text_comment[i])
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
  text_names                      text_comment
1    Abigail            Tommy sits next to XXX
2     Thomas  As a footballer XXX is very good
3    Abigail        XXX is a mature young lady
4     Thomas             XXX is a handsome man
5      Colin Tom is friends with Colin and Abi
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Florian. Thank you for your swift reply that I fully understand and see how it works. Now, if I tell you that the data frame of comments has over 111,000 rows and my nicknames file has a few thousand rows, I still have an aim to go for a route that doesn't create even larger data frames as intermediary steps, if at all possible......

Comment: I added a second solution based on your comment. This one prevents the creation of a large dataframe and yields the same result.